# Basic help on adding/subtracting in machine language

Tags: assembly, hex, machine-code

I'm currently getting started with learning machine language and assembly. The program I'm working on is rather simple, just basic adding and subtracting of decimal and hexadecimal numbers, but for some reason I cannot get the actual answer.

Disclaimer: Yes, this is a college assignment. No, I don't want you to do it for me. I asked my professor for help, but his explanation only confused me more - so I'm hoping the stackoverflow community can help clarify where my error is so I can fix it.

I'm running this in "sim" on the Windows platform which simulates the H1 and V1 computers, so it is a simulated environment.

Here's the log file:

```
Simulator Version 4.0               Fri Jan 29 17:15:56 2016

Machinecode file   = ex1-3b.mac   Size =  17 (hex) =   23 (dec)
Microcode file     = none         Size =  93 (hex) =  147 (dec)
Config file        = none
Log file           = ex1-3b.log
Answer file        = none
Simulation mode    = horizontal
Microlevel         = disabled
Shifter            = one-position
Cmd line addr      = F3C   (hex) =   3900 (dec)
Load point         = 0     (hex) =      0 (dec)
======================== Log Turned On  Fri Jan 29 17:15:56 2016
---- [T7] 0: st   /1 010/ g
  0: st   /1 010/ m[010]=002D/0000  
  1: add  /2 011/ ac=0000/0045  
  2: sub  /3 012/ ac=0045/0038  
  3: sub  /3 013/ ac=0038/0025  
  4: add  /2 014/ ac=0025/0030  
  5: add  /2 015/ ac=0030/002B  
  6: st   /1 016/ m[016]=0000/002B  
  7: hout /FFF9 / 002B
  8: dout /FFFD / 43
  9: halt /FFFF / 
Machine inst count =     A (hex) =     10 (dec)
---- [T7] d0
  0: 1010 2011 3012 3013 2014 2015 1016 FFF9    ........
  8: FFFD FFFF 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ........
 10: 0000 0045 000D 0013 000B FFFB 002B 0000    .E....+.
 18: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ........
```

So, what this is supposed to do is the following:

> 45(10) + 45(16) - 13(10) - 13(16) + b(16) + (-5)(10)

The (10) is base10 and the (16) is hexadecimal. For my own sanity, I converted the values to base10 when I input them into the program to keep them consistent (the t next to each number tells the compiler to use base10).

Here's my understanding of how this is working:

I tell it to load memory slot 10 (yes, I'm aware I'm wasting a lot of memory here) which I set to the initial value of 45. Then I add 45 in slot 11, subtract 13 in 12, 19 in 13 (the decimal form of 13 in hex), 11 in 14 and then -5 in 15. I then store this all in slot 16.

Next, I print the number stored in memory slot 16 in both hexadecimal and decimal form before halting the program.

Am I correct in all of this so far? Or did I go awry somewhere? That's what I'm curious about.

Right now I'm getting 43 as my result, but the actual end number should be 59 if my math is right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- According to an Android application I used, the result should be 88(10) / 58(16). At least the result should be even because you are adding 6 odd numbers, so I don't think it will be 59.
- I guess you should *load* (memory -> ac) instead of `st` (ac -> memory) as the first instruction.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I knew I had to be missing something small. I should've stored instead of loaded in slot 0. Once I did that I got the correct answer. Thanks for your help!